# Unexpected: HTTP request handler function called twice for each request

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    ///console.log(req);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
  console.log("Inside the handler function");
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Why is the Node.js code above printing out the console.log("Inside ...") message twice?  I expect it to print it once when the server receives one request from the client (browser).

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it's only one request from a browser? A scientific guess: a browser also tries to access `/favicon.ico`.

Comment: It print only once in my system? this Code works Fine

Comment: It also depends on how you are calling it. Are you doing it through postman or a client written by yourself?

Comment: @zerkms is probably right. You could print out the request URL to get some more insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome makes an extra request for the favicon.
Mozilla and Safari don't ..

Comment: i am using chrome and it does seem to add a request for favicon.